# Brightness level is not restored back after some idle time when using fglrx

Tags: xubuntu, power-management, brightness, fglrx, backlight

I have a laptop powered by fresh installation of `Ubuntu 12.04` with `XFCE`. Before I have used a default opensource ATI driver. For several days I have been using `fglrx`.

After some time of inactivity the brightness of display is automatically reduced to a minimal level. When I return back to the laptop by pressing any key or by moving mouse, the brightness level is automatically set to the largest (!) one. It really annoys.

1. Do I understand correctly that the idle timeout is managed by X.org/DPMS settings?
2. Who control the level of brightness which is restored after inactivity? I have not managed to find such settings in the Control Panel of ATI. I really want to change them.

There were no such problem with the opensource driver. `laptop-tools` are disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar set up and have been using a script found **[here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1954041)** also if you install **dconf-tools** "sudo apt-get install dconf-tools" launch and navigate to **org>gnome>settings-daemon>plugins>power** there should be some adjustments there, however I'm uncertain whether or not the settings there were placed by the previously mentioned script.

Answer (score 0):

Set brightness in ati control center in administrative mode.